# Avoid OutOfMemory when creating an image

Tags: java, out-of-memory, bufferedimage

I want to create a BufferedImage in a Java-Application. The users are allowed to change the dimensions of the image and I would like to allow images "as big as possible". 
How can I check, whether creating the BufferedImage would cause an OutOfMemory-Exception and recover from it?

Comment: try/catch with OutOfMemoryException ?

Comment: @Sebastian `OutOfMemoryException` does not exist. `OutOfMemoryError` does, and it is not a recommended practice to catch `Error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` to check the free memory of your JVM instance. And then based on this value you can add restrictions for dimensions for future image.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest approach. I will go with that one.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try catch is a simple way to do this

[Example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

Good luck

Comment: From the [`Error` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html): *«An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.»*

Answer (score 0):

Try to allocate as much as memory when running application.

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024M
```

Above argument will allocate 1GB memory.

Comment: My question is in no way related to the amount of allocated memory.

Comment: I know its not related but this will help you to avoid this error. If you get error even after setting 1GB then your code is not efficient.

Comment: This topic has nothing to do with the efficiency, I simply want to allocate as much space as possible for a simple BufferedImage.